# Find maximum number of scholarships without exceeding total value of 500000

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I  have a `.csv` file in the form:

```
ID        scholarship amount       applicant  experience
1          45000                           8
2          65000                           10
3          38000                           11
4          62000                           12
5          45000                           9
6          58000                           11
7          28000                           12
8          78000                           12
9          52500                           7
10         45000                           10
```

The question is write a code that finds maximum number of scholarships that can be offered  without exceeding a total value  of  `500000`.  Only consider   applicants with `10` or more years of  experience.
I have tried   `df[df['applicant experience']  >=10]`  but still I am obtaining  records with  total scholarship amount  above `500000`.
Please help

Comment: Welcome to SO, I think if you put ur code people will clearly understand what you have done and where is your problem.

Comment: You're on the right track. The next step would be to sort the scholarship values of that subset, so you know which ones are the cheapest, and then take the cumulative sum to see how much it will cost you to pay for the X cheapest scholarships.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[(df.scholarship amount <=500000)&(df.applicant experience >=10)]
```

try this code
and its better to change the column name give column name without spaces 
**scholarship_amout ,applicant_experience** rather than **scholarship amount,applicant experience**

Comment: Ok  but it's not the scholarship amount that must be less than 500000 but rather the  total sumof scholarships must not exceed

Comment: please describe the question properly i cannot understand properly